# Spring Redirect Url: SavedRequest is null when session expires

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm accessing the SavedRequest in the login controller to set the redirect url in the login form. When the session expires (or first login after server is started), savedRequest is null.

If I access a url in a fresh browser session, saved request is available.

Any way i can access the redirect url consistently from the login controller?

NB. I'm using spring 3.2.3..from what I can tell savedRequest is no longer accessbile from the session.

**login.jsp**

```
<form   action="${actionUrl}" method='POST' autocomplete='off'>
    <span class="box-label">Username:</span>
    <input type="text" name="j_username" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" data-dojo-props="style:{width:'150px'}">

<span class="box-label">Password:</span>
<input type="password" name="j_password" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" data-dojo-props="style:{width:'150px'}">
<input type="submit" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="label:'Login'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="${redirect}">   

</form>
```

**Login Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(final HttpSession session, final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request,
    final HttpServletResponse response) {
    addRedirectUrlToModel(model, request, response);
    return "login";

}
private void addRedirectUrlToModel(final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
    if (savedRequest != null) {
        model.addAttribute("redirect", savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
    } else {
        System.out.println("saved request is null");
    }
}
```

**Security config:**

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <sec:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailHandler" />
    <sec:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/error/not-authorised"/>

    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"
                            invalid-session-url="/login/sessionExpired"
                            session-authentication-error-url="/login/alreadyLoggedIn"
                            >
        <sec:concurrency-control    max-sessions="1"
                                    expired-url="/login/sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin"
                                    error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
    </sec:session-management>
```

Comment: The request is stored in the session, so indeed after a timeout the session and thus the stored request is gone.

Comment: This also happens when the session is ended by session mngmt (due to login in another browser/machine)

Comment: Yes everything that will trigger session destruction will lead to this behavior. No session, no saved request.

Comment: any other way to get the redirect url?

e.g. if i try to access http://localhost/app/my/page and get redirected to http://localhost/app/login .. i want to access http://localhost/app/my/page in my logincontroller

Comment: Store it in the form as a hidden param (maybe encrypted). If you store it/rely on the session and there is no session it will fail.

Comment: yep, that's what i'm doing, but the controller needs to access it to include it in the form as a model attribute. spring automatically redirects to the url in a the redirect field of the login form.

Comment: If you are in the same request as the one that is rendering the login-form you still should have access to the saved-request. Currently it looks like you are redirecting (and trying to get the url) after the login (instead whilst rendering the initial form).

Comment: I added some controller code to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get the `savedrequest` of the **expire** `session`, it will come null. You can fix this by **creating** a new `DefaultSavedRequest`. After creating the `DefaultSavedRequest`, you can **set** into the `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` and move it during the session in different requests.

```
private void addRedirectUrlToModel(final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {

        SavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request, new PortResolverImpl());

        request.getSession().setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST", savedRequest);
        
        if (savedRequest != null) {
            model.addAttribute("redirect", savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
        } else {
            System.out.println("saved request is null");
        }
}
```